# support of Numeric password box in windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, numeric, passwordbox

I am developing windows phone 7 application where i need to put the input scope of password box as numeric, say in case of ATM pin, but there is no way seen as of now where i can show numeric keypad for inputting pin or no way to assign asteric characters to textBox with numeric input scope. Is there any workaround for the same, or will it be supported in mango version of WP7?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [NumericPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) InputScope.

But as you figured out, you need a custom `TextBox` implementation. I would suggest using the  `PhoneTextBox` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com)

Comment: Thnx Claus, finally i have used the customized password box, that solved all my queries. Actually NumericPassword is included in InputScope() API in 7.1 sdk, but it not yet implemented.